# File explorer hides when it losses focus on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, crash, filemanager

When I open a File Explorer window and as soon as I switch to another window (without closing File Explorer) the File Explorer window hides and it even does not show any status on task bar. So anything opened and focus lost is no more visible. I even don't see any error or warning message on screen. How can I fix the problem.

Comment: Taskbar... which Ubuntu are you running, it's Gnome or Unity?

Comment: Its ubuntu unity